# Add View to a Fragment Dynamically in Android?

Tags: android-fragments, android, android-view

Is it possible to add a View to a Fragment dynamically? If it is, how can i do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is it possible to add a View to a Fragment dynamically?

Yes.

> If it is, how can i do that?

The same way you would add a `View` anywhere else: call `addView()` on the `View`'s parent container.

Comment: i seems there is no api addView() in Fragment class.

Comment: @MS: That is because `Fragment` isn't a `ViewGroup` or even a `View`. A `Fragment` might *hold* a `ViewGroup`.

Answer (score -1):

```
HomeFragment frag = new HomeFragment();
FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.replace(R.id.fragLogin, frag);
ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.right_in, R.anim.right_out);
ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
ft.commit();
```

Here,`R.id.fragLogin` is the id of your first fragment which you have declared in your activities xml and HomeFragment is your second Fragment.